# Pyramid session object disappears after ~20 mins

Tags: python, pyramid

Setting a variable in `request.session` with

```
request.session['display_name'] = 'foo'
```

and then displaying throughout my app with

```
request.session.display_name
```

Which works just fine throughout the app. If left alone for about 20 minutes however, I can no longer call it. I get:

```
AttributeError: 'CookieSession' object has no attribute 'display_name'
```

Reading up on how pyramid [sessions](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/session.html#module-pyramid.session) are supposed to work, it should still exist for duration of the browser scope.

Any ideas why it gets removed after a while?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the definition for [timeout](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/session.html#pyramid.session.SignedCookieSessionFactory):

> A number of seconds of inactivity before a session times out. If None then the cookie never expires. This lifetime only applies to the value within the cookie. Meaning that if the cookie expires due to a lower max_age, then this setting has no effect. Default: 1200.

Assuming you don't set `max_age`, or if you set `max_age` to be 1200 or greater, then the default setting of `timeout` (1200 seconds) will expire the cookie at that elapsed duration.

1200 seconds / 60 seconds per minute = 20 minutes

...which is consistent with your experience.

Try setting `timeout` to your desired duration in seconds, or to `None` to prevent the expiration of the cookie while the browser is open.

Comment: I see, this makes sense though I don't know of a real use case where you would want to expire cookie values before the cookie itself.